# Webrtc, ICE failure

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, webrtc

The video call works fine within the same network. The problem is while calling computer on other network, the remote video doesn't show up. On chrome I don't get any errors in the console, but on firefox console Im getting **"ICE Failure"**.

Im using Node JS for implementing signaling server and Google STUN Server.

Following is the sequence of events im using:

User A:

1. Creates **Peerconnection** (includes getusermedia, addstream)
2. registers **onIcecandidate** handler
3. emits a socket event to notify **User B** about the call and waits for response
4. Receives **Offer** from **User B** and creates **answer**.

User B:

1. Receives the socket event and creates **Peerconnection** (includes getusermedia, addstream)
2. registers **onicecandidate** handler
3. Also registers **"Onnegogiationneeded"** handler. **User A** doesn't have this handler. It is removed so that the User B gets enough time to create  **Peerconnection**,**candidate** handlers and then create an **Offer**
4. When **Onnegogiation** is triggered, an **offer** is created and sent to User A

**NOTE:**
 1. Im creating **peerconnection** and **onicecandidate** handlers on both sides before creating Offer. 
 2. It was done to make sure that **Onicecandiate** handler is ready on both sides much before the offer is created and no **ICE Candidates** are missed.

Is there anything wrong with the above sequence of events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can debug and fix the issue in following sequence :

1. Check the sdp and candidates being exchanged.
2. If any of the STUn candidates i mean srflx or prflx are exchanged , negotiated we need to check whether they were used later to exchange media or not.If not STUN server is not configured properly, kindly correct.
   3.If the STUN candidates being exchanged still you are facing this issue which means one of the candidate in different network is behind symmetric firewall.In that case one needs to configure TURN server. You can use any freely available TURN server or deploy our own TS or use some paid service.Make sure you are configuring the TURN server well as per your firewall. Mostly TURN server are not freely available.

4.If still you are facing issue which means there is some issue with firewall, desired port be it for STUN,TURN server or negotiated ports are not open in your firewall. In this case test your setup in open network. If that works one has to open those ports/IPs and configure firewall accordingly.

PS : You might not find any logs in chrome console but in chrome://webrtc-internals you will find very rich information which will be useful for you in debugging and fixing your issue.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Its working properly when one them is using a  Mobile data connection. But when both clients are using WiFi, the remote video is not being loaded. As you said I will try to configure TURN server. Is there a way to make it work through STUN ?

Comment: If its not working in WiFI then surely the issue is in Firewall either its symmetric or desired UDP Ports/IP are blocked. In first case you have to use TURN server and in second case unblock required ports/IP. In order to make it work via STUN firewall needs to be modified if allowed.

Comment: Is anything possible through UDP hole punching? I am not sure about it ..Im just asking..

Comment: Can i recreate Offer using the existing connection? Would that make any difference if its not Asymmetric NAT?

Comment: UDP hole punching is taken care by STUN and TURN for their respective candidates it's part of both protocols.Regarding symmetric NAT one has to find the way to configure webRTC stack to retain existing connection and ideally its good optimization.

Comment: So as of now there is no way to transverse a Symmetric NAT. Using a TURN server is the only option.

Comment: @Black Correct, TS is only option for symmetric NAT

Comment: Would suggest to please upvote the relevant comments so that others facing similar issues will get benefited as yours else SO will delete those over a period of time.